# OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY Crypto SSL error when trying to configure in CMake

Tags: cmake, openssl, azerothcore

This is my first time trying to install Azerothcore. I followed a few (I would say up to a year old) ways of installing Azerothcore but every time I seem to have a hiccup when it comes to the OpenSSL. I think I have followed the process to a 'T' but obviously not. I have a window that pops up saying Error in configuration process project files may be invalid.

The 2 CMake errors I get when following the Azerothcore guide are:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
  system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY Crypto
  SSL)

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  src/cmake/macros/FindOpenSSL.cmake:559 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  deps/openssl/CMakeLists.txt:17 (find_package)

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log"
```

I've been following the Azerothcore install guide for Windows 11

Win64OpenSSL-3_2_0

cmake-3.25.2-windows-i386

boost_1_81_0-msvc-14.3-64

mysqlcommunity-8.0.33.0

visual studio 2022

I'm looking to play offline due to no internet access where I work and I obviously have no programming experience but I'm ok at getting around a computer and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Use OpenSSL 3.0

Comment: @Kitzunu I removed the Win64OpenSSL-3_2_0 file and replaced it with the Win64OpenSSL-3_0_12 file and restarted the computer but still get the same error. I'm going to completely remove everything and start over again for the third time lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMake cannot find the OpenSSL directory on your machine. It looks for it by default under the OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR system variable. Make sure it is set properly.

Comment: I tried to add C:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64 under the Value column in CMake to OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR but that still brought up the same errors. Am I looking in the right place or am I in over my head? How do I make sure it is set properly as you said? I'm honestly not sure what I'm doing even after trying to google things.

Comment: Make sure your file path points to the include folder...

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too, so make sure you have the OpenSSL version 3.0 and your OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR and OPENSSL_LIB_DIR have proper paths, mine are C:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64 and C:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64/include .
One of the issues you could have is that the OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR config doesn't exist for you so you must add a new entry with the +Add Entry button.